# IMFCore Installation Error trying to install this POD but it show's me error

Tags: objective-c, ibm-cloud, push, ibm-mobile-services

I'm Trying Install the Pod 'IMFCore' and end with error and redirection to toolchains site 
below is the error which I get

```
Installing IMFCore (1.2.1)

[!] Error installing IMFCore
```

and I have tried with BMSSerurity it works only with swift and I have Objective c codes

```
Installing IMFCore (1.2.1)

[!] Error installing IMFCore

[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://hub.jazz.net/git/bluemixmobilesdk/imf-ios-sdk.git /var/folders/l1/zppm8kgj0mqb858x70xkk4y80000gn/T/d20190326-13318-19b93nw --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.2.1

Cloning into '/var/folders/l1/zppm8kgj0mqb858x70xkk4y80000gn/T/d20190326-13318-19b93nw'...

fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://hub.jazz.net/git/bluemixmobilesdk/imf-ios-sdk.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack

redirect: https://console.bluemix.net/devops/try-toolchains
```

Answer (score 0):

IMFCore is deprecated - https://cocoapods.org/pods/IMFCore

Use the swift frameworks and write a wrapper in swift to bridge between the Obj-C and swift frameworks.